# Having problems displaying images in Code::Blocks using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks

Recently, I changed my PC and when I run the C++ program using OpenCV library inside Code::Blocks in Ubuntu 12.04, there is a message " init done, opengl support available" and the window shape of displaying the images is different from my previous PC with the same C++ program. I want to show two images in one window using opencv but the problem is that the quality of images are low and some times a part of one image is in the other image. I ran the exact program in my old PC and there was no problem at all. Would someone please help me with that? I also uploaded one image from the problem of displaying.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the "expected" behavior?

Comment: I attached the expected behaviour that is from my old PC.